# Need to add class values on Tabbed Panel tabs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need to add class (cls) values to the actual tabs in a tabbed panel (for test automation purposes).

I assumed that this would solve this :

```
component1.title = "1";
component2.title = "2";
component3.title = "3";

component1.cls = "1";
component2.cls = "2";
component3.cls = "3";

var v = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
    items: [
        component1,
        component2,
        component3,
    ]
});
```

However **component.cls = "1"** just adds class values to the tabbed panel body elements, not the actual tabs above.

**EDIT: Correct answer below.** To apply the answer to my problem, I added the tabConfig to my component like so :

```
component1.title = "1";
component1.cls = "1";
component1.tabConfig = {
    cls: 'foo'
}

Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
    items: [
        component1
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
new Ext.tab.Panel({
    items: [{
        title: 'Foo',
        tabConfig: {
            cls: 'foo'
        }
    }]
});
```

Docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel